# How to get the offset for every char from a given standard input in c++?

Tags: c++, stdin, offset

The given script which can’t be changing is;

```
cat mytext.txt | ./myfunction
```

I want to get index for every char from mytext.txt
Assume that mytext.txt contains “Hello World it is a test”.

I add the whole content into an array.

```
int main(){ ....
   char array[100];
   fgets(array,30,stdin);
 }
```

Now I want to get char and its index from array after whitespace.

> Output should be like this ;

- Hello 0
- World 6
- it 12
- is 15

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Open the file. Iterate on each character. Whenever you get a space new word starts. You can do it. What have you tried so far? Just do it :)

Comment: You could use `strtok()` for this.  Then for each token (word), subtract `array` to get the offset.

Comment: Assuming the file stream is `is`, use `is.tellg` and `is >> word`.

Comment: O.T., nit-picking: If you declare a `char array[100];` why do you read `fgets(array,30,stdin);`? Do you think 70 unused extra bytes make it more safe? ;-) Wouldn't it be better to denote the exact length? E.g. `fgets(array, sizeof array, stdin);` This would even work if you later decide to change `array` to `char array[200];` or `char array[10];` (Or even better, write it in C++ with `std::string` and stream I/O.)

Comment: @Scheff, the given code is pretty much C, so I stuck with that.  Maybe the tags should be modified.  Also, does `cin.tellg()` even work ?

Comment: @SidS _Also, does `cin.tellg()` even work ?_ Nope. :-(

Comment: @SidS Finally, it probably has to be done like recommended by @Cherubim (except the _Open the file._ which doesn't make sense for `std::cin`.)

Comment: Can I open file without using any argument after ./myfunction? How can I get the file name when the content of the file are piped in script?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a vector or a string to find out the position. A text stream is a sequence of characters. An input stream has a **get position** - the position from which it reads (`0` for `Hello`, `5` for the first `space`, `6` for `world`, etc.). All you have to do is read from stream and ask for current position. You do this with [`tellg`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/tellg) - *TELL Get position*.

Some other things you may find helpful:

1. [ws](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ws) - discards white-spaces. You will need it to skip the white-spaces between words.
2. When you read in a string, the reading stops at first white-space. So, on first call `is >> word` will load `Hello` into `word`.
3. When you open a file you always have to check the file was successfully opened. Use the full path:

   ```
   ifstream is{"c:\\temp\\test.txt"};
   if ( !is )
     return -1;
   ```

Good luck!